# How to use the built-in rich text editor in Rails 6.0 with activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6

I've recently upgraded to Rails version 6.0 because of the new built-in rich text editor functionality. However, I'm unable to integrate the built-in rich text editor with activeadmind using formatics. I know there are pretty good gem plugins for activeadmind that I can use to achieve the same goal. However, I would like to use the built-in functionality of Rails 6.0.

Comment: have you found any solution so far?

Comment: No, @goodniceweb

Answer (score -4):

Use this blog maybe its help you to achieve your goal: 
https://medium.com/better-programming/quick-look-at-action-text-in-rails-6-0-12a8f9f7597f

rails action_text:install

has_rich_text :text used in the model and

In form use this syntax    <%= form.rich_text_area :text %>

`rich-text area ready for use`

Comment: This shows how to use it a regular rails view, but the OP is about using it in ActiveAdmin view